# Laravel Livewire Component not reading simple html parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Just started using Laravel Livewire and I have a problem with passing parameters to a livewire component.

**Home.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>
        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        @livewireStyles
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased p-10">
        
        <livewire:forms.input type="text" name="Test" />

        @livewireScripts
    </body>
</html>
```

**Component**

```
<div class="FormsInput">
    @isset($label)
    <label for="{{ $name }}">{{ $label }}</label>
    @endisset
    <div class="">
        <input wire:model="{{ $name }}" type="{{ $type }}" name="{{ $name }}" id="{{ $name }}" placeholder="{{ $placeholder }}">
    </div>
    @isset($helper)
    <div class="">
        {{ $label }}
    </div>
    @endisset
    <div class="">
        {{ $error }}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Http/Livewire/Forms/Input**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Forms;

use Livewire\Component;

class Input extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.forms.input');
    }
}
```

This is the error that I get:

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable $name
```

[image]

Comment: Forgot the [property](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this error you have to do two things:

1. Add name property to your component because Livewire components store and track data as public properties on the component class.

```php
class Input extends Component
{
   public string $name;

     ...
}
```

2. Use property name on wire:model without '$'

```php
<input wire:model="name" ... />
```

You can find data binding on Livewire docs at this [Link](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#data-binding).